# How can I drop out of the loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, break

I try to write a function which can rotate the array to the left,eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 
and turn to 4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3. At first place, I use this funciton below ,but the result is 4,2,3,7,5,6,1,8,9.
Therefore, I think it does not drop out of the loop because it only executes once in the loop. Please anyone could help me with this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```js
var a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var len =a.length;
for (i=0;i<3;i++ )
{   
    var b = a[i];
    var j = i;
    for(k=0;k<a.length;k++)
      {
        j+=3;
        if(j<a.length)
        {
            a[i] = a[j];
            i=j;
        }
        else {
            j-=3;
            a[j]=b;
            break;
        }

    }   
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp might have some ideas for you to simplify your logic.  Maybe an existing wheel would be just as good as reinventing one yourself.

Comment: I don't think you have any basis for "it doesn't work because it doesn't drop out of a loop."  Your code simply doesn't work.  Rewrite it so that it does.  Suggestion: begin with the part of the array starting at 4 first, put that into your target array, then put in the 1,2,3 part

Comment: Code can be done in 2 lines `var a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var removed = a.splice(0,3);
a.concat(removed); console.log(a);`

Comment: For those of you suggesting splice, there's probably other motivations for writing this code that the OP hasn't articulated.

Comment: Reread your code and think about what exactly it is doing. That might help

Comment: Hi,guys.I know use splice is more easier, but  I just want to try what I learned form Progarmming Pearls( Jon Bentley) into practice.Thanks guys~!

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns w3schools *very* often contains inaccurate, incomplete, or misleading information and as such is a really poor resource. Always [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) documentation over w3schools

Comment: @NickWEI you are using an implicit global variable in your for loop. This is a common beginner mistake but it is a bad code smell. You need to put `var` or `let` (It is 2020, you should be using `let` over `var` in virtually all situations) before your variable: `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMIrving … the thing I like about this particular site is you can type in stuff and see it immediately.  It may not be 100% accurate (gasp! No!) but it is useful to see how stuff works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want algorithm with no array methods you can do it like this :

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(a);

//Iteration of rotation (Here rotated left 3 times) this can be as many as you want.
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
  //Store 'First Member' and 'Last Index' of array
  let last = a.length - 1;
  let first = a[0];

  //Loop to store every (n+1)th term to nth except the last one
  for(let j=0;j<last;j++){
    a[j] = a[j+1];
  }

  //Finally add first item to last index
  a[last] = first; 
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the approach you are using, but using `shift` and `push` will achieve this very easily:

```js
var a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var len = a.length;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  a.push(a.shift());
}

console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3
```

`shift` removes the *first* item from an array.  Here are some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for it.

`push` pushes an item onto the *end* of an array.  Here are some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for it.

Comment: You are using an implicit global for `i` just like OP did. This is a code smell.